# why won't right, left, width, height work on UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm following a tutorial for a messaging chat app and I keep getting errors on the UIImageViews. For example ~ userImageView.right, userImageView.width, etc. all get errors saying UIImageView has no member.  I've used the right/width/height in other parts of my app, I can't figure out why it's not happy here... thoughts?

```
class ConversationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

static let identifier = "ConversationTableViewCell"

private let userImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return imageView
}()

private let userNameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 21, weight: .semibold)
    return label
}()

private let userMessageLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 19, weight: .regular)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.addSubview(userImageView)
    contentView.addSubview(userNameLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(userMessageLabel)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    userImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10,
                                 y: 10,
                                 width: 100,
                                 height: 100)

    userNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: userImageView.right + 10,
                                 y: 10,
                                 width: contentView.width - 20 - userImageView.width,
                                 height: (contentView.height-20)/2)

    userMessageLabel.frame = CGRect(x: userImageView.right + 10,
                                    y: userNameLabel.bottom + 10,
                                    width: contentView.width - 20 - userImageView.width,
                                    height: (contentView.height-20)/2)

}
```

Comment: "I've used the right/width/height in other parts of my app" Really? Well, they are not built-in Swift / Cocoa UIImageView properties, so either you are lying about that or else you imported some sort of third party library, or used an extension on UIView or UIImageView, that is not in scope here. Do this: find some code where this works, find where it says `right`, and Command-click on it. That will take you to where this is defined. That is what you need to be importing / seeing here as well.

Comment: why the anger?  I'm new to coding & I thought I had used it elsewhere but upon reviewing the rest of my app I had not.  I think the tutorial i'm following has an extension file for these properties, I will try that.

Comment: No anger, just stating the possibilities. And it seems, indeed, that I stated them correctly. I was right the first time: you were lying. (Not on purpose, of course.)  I knew it was perfectly possible that you _thought_ you said `someImageView.right` elsewhere but you didn't; and if you _had_ said it elsewhere, the explanation I gave for how that was possible was helpful and correct. Thus my comment covers all the logical possibilities. That is what we are here to do. I'm exemplifying for you how programmers think. In fact, a key pro debugging technique is to question your own assumptions.

Comment: And as a practical matter, since "I've used the right/width/height in other parts of my app" turns out to be false, I suggest you delete the question.

Comment: The term "lying" seems loaded. It implies deliberate deception. "mistaken" would be less of an accusation.

Comment: @DuncanC It doesn't imply that. It can mean that, but it can just mean "utter a falsehood". And it isn't the mistake that I want to refer, it's the utterance (i.e. the claim in the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new swift file and add following code in that and everything will be good to go.

```swift
extension UIView {
    public var width: CGFloat {
        return frame.size.width
    }
    
    public var height: CGFloat {
        return frame.size.height
    }
    
    public var top: CGFloat {
        return frame.origin.y
    }

    public var left: CGFloat {
        return frame.origin.x
    }

    public var bottom: CGFloat {
        return top + height
    }

    public var right: CGFloat {
        return left + width
    }
}
```

**Or:**

More easy way to just import this package [AATools](https://github.com/AafaqAhmed6296/AATools.git) in your project, it contains many handy extensions for speedy development.

Answer (score 1):

A `UIImageView` is a `UIView` object. As such it has a frame property, which is a `CGRect`.

You can use `someImageView.frame` to get to the view's frame.

`CGRect`s have properties `size.height` and `size.width`. They also have properties `maxX` and `maxY`, which are equivalent to `right` and `bottom`. (actually, it seems `CGRect` also has properties `height` and `width`, so you can skip the "size." prefix.)

So for an imageView `someImageView`:

```
height = someImageView.frame.height 
width = someImageView.frame.width
right = someImageView.frame.maxX
bottom = someImageView.frame.maxY
```

If you want you could add an extension to UIView that added the properties height, width, right, and bottom as in @afaq’s answer. (Voted)